# How do I extract and execute a target from a std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

I have something equal to this:

```
auto dummy(std::function<int(int)> ifunc) {
  auto vals = std::vector<int>(1000000);
  for(auto& v: vals) {
    v = ifunc(v);
  }
}
```

Assuming the `std::function` does not bind to a lambda with state (althrough it might be bound to a lambda without state), what is the correct way of extracting the underlaying function pointer and exectuing it instead of the `std::function`?

This is my attempt, but it crashes regardles if I dereference the target or not.

```
auto dummy(std::function<int(int)> ifunc) {
  auto vals = std::vector<int>(1000000);
  auto&& target = *ifunc.target<int(int)>();
  for(auto& v: vals) {
    v = target(v);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What is the actual the problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about extracting the underlying function pointer; but the problem to which you believe the solution is to extract the underlying function pointer -- which makes no sense since `std::function` is an alias for the underlying function pointer, offers no other functionality is of itself, so there's never any valid reason to need the underlying function pointer in the first place.

Comment: 1) Why can't you call `ifunc` directly? 2) Why don't you use a function pointer in the first place if you don't want `std::function`?

Comment: If you are positive that `ifunc` can always be converted to a function pointer, why are you passing an `std::function` to begin with?

Comment: This [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) uses different syntax. Try `ifunc.target<int(*)(int)>()` and check if it returned a `nullptr`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - "Never any need" is not entirely true. If interfacing a C library, it could speed things along to pass the users function pointer directly if possible. The OP's example isn't that, however.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Because it's less assembler code to invoke a function pointer than a std::function, and I want better performance in this piece of code as it's invoked many times. Might be a micro optimization - yes, but I do not know until I've profiled it. Also, I prefer passing around std::function than function pointers.

Comment: "Less assembler code" is a meaningless statement unless you can back it up with assembly that was emitted with high optimization levels.

Comment: @n.m. It crashes in Visual Studio and this is therefore such an example.

Comment: @n.m. It says "Runtime Error". Looks reproduced to me.

Comment: Profile, think of an optimisation, in that order. No exceptions.

Comment: @StoryTeller: https://godbolt.org/g/KfLGp4

Comment: @nwp it doesn't to me.

Comment: Your demonstration is invalid as you don't include the cost of calling `target` into equation.

Comment: @nwp sorry it does say it to me, my mistake.

Comment: Have you ever heard the term "premature optimization"? Unless you are restricted in code size (in which case using `std::function` is highly suspect anyway) those few extra instructions are hardly going to matter much. Not to mention those jumps will be handled well enough by a branch predictor in the case of a loop, as you have.

Comment: @ViktorSehr Also note that converting `std::function` to a raw pointer requires even more assembly: https://godbolt.org/g/SffZYu If you use `std::function` everywhere then stick to it.

Comment: Sorry, I hav jumped to conclusions too early. `target` cannot extract a regular function pointer from an `std::function` bound to a lambda. It could extract a lambda if you knew its type, but you don't. Thee only thing you can do is convert a lambda to a raw function pointer when creating an `std::function`.

Comment: @n.m You mean the cost of extracting the target from the std::function. As it is only performed once, as oppossed to 100000 times I consider it negligable.

Comment: @freakish See previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that `std::function` exists is to provide an **abstraction** of a function that has a particular signature. The **actual** function (or function object) held in the `std::function` object does not have to have the signature that the `std::function` object provides. For example, your `function<int(int)>` object could hold a pointer to a function that takes `double` and returns `char`; the code inside the `std::function` object takes care of the conversions.

The `target` template member function returns a pointer to the target object **only if** the target object has the **exact type** specified by the template argument to `target`. So, for example, if the target object takes a `double` and returns `char`, the calling `ifunc.target<char(double)>` will give you back a pointer to that function. Calling it with any other argument type will give you back a null pointer.

In the code presented here, the call is `ifunc.target<int(int)>()`, and that will return a null pointer unless the **exact type** of the target object is "function taking `int` and returning `int`".

If you're going to use this template member function, you **must** check for a null pointer before doing anything else with the returned value.

Comment: And in this example, the **exact type** is unnameable, because it is `[some lambda type]::operator()`

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to make it work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

auto dummy(std::function<int(int)> ifunc) {
  auto vals = std::vector<int>(10);
  auto&& target = *ifunc.target<int(*)(int)>(); //added the missing (*)
  assert(target);
  for(auto& v: vals) {
    v = target(v);
  }
}

int main() {
    dummy(+[](int x) {return x+1;}); //explicitly decay to function pointer
    return 0;
}
```

Note the added `(*)` to get the syntax right (`std::function` is storing a function pointer, not a function) and that we have to explicitly decay the lambda into a function pointer.

Since you can't really know the type of the lambdas you would have to go through the code and add a `+` where possible or wrap the lambda into a `decay_if_possible`-function before passing it to `std::function`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to get the target for making the call to the function faster. Let me propose a solution that don't require your functoin to be callable with only one type possible.

By the way, the fact that you need to send the exact type in `target` makes your function effectively callable with that type only. At that point, you shouldn't hide it and take that type as parameter to the function. Let me explain:

```
// If ifunc don't contain a int(*)(int), runtime error!
auto&& target = ifunc.target<int(*)(int)>();
```

Your code will compile if you send any other types, such as lambdas, but will make a runtime error.

By taking the parameter by that type, it indeed makes your code callable with that type only, but when trying to call it with another type, it result in a compile time error:

```
auto dummy(int(*ifunc)(int)) { // safer!
  auto vals = std::vector<int>(1000000);
  for(auto& v: vals) {
    v = ifunc(v);
  }
}
```

But what if you need speed *and* you need to call your function with any closure type? There's a language feature that exist just for that: templates!

```
template<typename F>
auto dummy(F function) { // safer, faster than function pointer, and scalable
  auto vals = std::vector<int>(1000000);

  for(auto& v: vals) {
    v = function(v);
  }
}
```

This version is even faster than pointer to function. Since the code is templated, the function you are sending there has a much greater chance to be inlined. You can see the [resulting assembly for yourself](https://godbolt.org/g/SqZt3W).

By the way,

> (althrough it might be bound to a lambda without state)

Not quite. You must explicitly convert the lambda to a function pointer first, or the internal closure type will still be the type of the lambda.